# Access permission denied for the objects created by someone else in my AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an application that writes files to an Amazon S3 bucket. I am not able to download or copy the files to different bucket. I am getting `access denied` error. The owner of the file is someone else but the bucket is owned by us. That person is not accessible and is not there in the organization. How do I access the files and change the access permission or change the owner of the files?

I tried copying the objects from source bucket to destination bucket but `Error 403`.

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "abcd",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "abcd",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/xxx"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xyz"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected: I want to move these files to different bucket or download these files. It is giving error `Access denied 403`.

Comment: Do you have the access rights to change the IAM policy? You may need to contact the AWS support.

Comment: This is normally a side-effect of copying objects between AWS Accounts. Were the objects copied from a different Account? Do you have access to that other account?

Comment: @Juned, I have access to IAM Policy to my aws account

Comment: @John, I dont have access to any other AWS Account or access to that person who created the objects.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you'll need to contact AWS Support.

Answer (score 2):

The uploader of the files needs to [grant full control over the objects](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/) to the bucket owner.

How you do this depends on which tool or SDK you are using to upload files. For example, if you are using the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) then you would append `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` to the `aws s3 cp` command.

As an S3 bucket owner, you can [require uploaders to give you full control](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/) by specifying an appropriate S3 bucket policy.

Note that giving the bucket owner full control does not make the bucket owner the owner of the objects. They are still owned by the uploader. However, if the bucket owner has full control and wants ownership, then the bucket owner can simply copy each file over itself, and that will transfer the ownership.

Comment: thanks. Since i need the full control, if i copy the object to itself, will the file get corrupt..etc as files belong to production env

Comment: If you take ownership of the files, you still have full control. I'm not sure what your question about corrupt files is, but if you copy a file over itself in S3, it will not get corrupted. Of course, you should test these processes on non-prod systems before you endanger any production systems. That should be a given when it comes to receiving advice from the internet.

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to update the file to itself. It is giving access denied error. I tried to give ACL permissions to the file but i am getting Access denied error. I am not sure, what else can i try to access the files in the bucket. Any more suggestions will help